# Have semaphore-like behaviour on main thread in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin

I have a method called `showProgress` which runs a fade animation and switches the current view with a page that shows just a loading spinner (ProgressBar).

```
fun showProgress(show: Boolean, progressView: ProgressBar, layoutView: View): Completable {
    val showView = if (show) progressView else layoutView
    val hideView = if (show) layoutView else progressView

    return fadeAnimation(showView, hideView)
}

private fun fadeAnimation(showView: View, hideView: View): Completable {
    return Completable.create {
        //        animateSemaphore.acquire()
        Log.d("beforeFade", "showView: ${showView.visibility}; hideView: ${hideView.visibility}")
        val animTime: Long = showView.context.applicationContext.resources.getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime).toLong()

        showView.alpha = 0f
        handler.post {
            showView.visibility = View.VISIBLE

            showView.animate()
                    .alpha(1f)
                    .setDuration(animTime)
                    .setListener(null)

            hideView.animate()
                    .alpha(0f)
                    .setDuration(animTime)
                    .setListener(object : AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                        override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator) {
                            hideView.visibility = View.GONE
                            Log.d("fade", "showView: ${showView.visibility}; hideView: ${hideView.visibility}")
                            it.onComplete()
                        }
                    })
        }
    }
}
```

I use it when I'm waiting for a network request to complete with RxJava and I want to show the ProgressBar while the app is waiting for the request to finish. However, sometimes the network request will return before `showProgress` is finished and will cause the animation to run twice causing progressView and layoutView to both be set to `View.GONE`.

My question is how do I make sure that when `showProgress` is called while another `showProgress` is still running, the `showProgress` being called will wait till the one running is finished? Just an FYI, semaphores won't exactly work since `showProgress` runs on the main thread and will cause a running `showProgress` to freeze.

Comment: Sounds like a CountDownLatch might be what you need. You can use the Java one or roll your own.

Comment: But this looks like something that would block the calling thread in this case would be the main thread.

Comment: if I get this correctly, use animator.cancel() to cancel animating and animate from current value (not start)

Comment: @urSus so this will move the animation to the end state synchronously?

Comment: not by it self, you have to override onAnimationCanceled